# jQuery call plugin with own init function

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, init

I started trying to create my own plugin using jQuery and the prototype function.
My code looks like the following:

```
var Slider = function(element, controls, interval) {
    this.element = element;
    this.controls = controls;
    this.interval = interval || 5000;

    this.init();
};

Slider.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        if (this.controls)
            this.setControls();

        this.element.hide();
        this.slides[0].show();
        this.fadeIt();
    }
}
```

And inside prototype are more functions.
Currently I'm creating a slider by calling the following:

```
new Slider($(".slide"), $(".slider").find(".controls").find("i"), 6000);
```

But how I want to do is is something like this:

```
Slider.init({
   element: $(".slide"),
   controls: $(".slider").find(".controls").find("i"),
   interval: 6000,
});
```

I tried searching for a solutions but I only could find how to make something like this:

```
$(".slider").Slider();
```

Anyone who can help me out or knows what to search for?
Thanks instead!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking up "jQuery Plugin init" when I found your question. I also found [this great article](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/) with a jQuery Plugin boilerplate that include an `init()` function.